# What is the cost of google cloud platform for Blaze plan?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am planning to use BigQuery for my mobile application, which will be using Firebase analytics data. What I understand from the docs is that I need to use Blaze plan in order to do that . I have followed this link .

https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

In the link below in that page ,there is a calculator for blaze plan,but that calculator does not include "Google Cloud Platform" option for calculation. So can someone explain how does the pricing for that works ? Or is it that the data part under cloud functions mean the same ? So the amount of data depicting user hits and parameters amount to that 5Gb free downloadable data ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Off topic as question about licensing and prizing

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Platform (like Firebase itself) has many features, each with its own pricing scheme.

The cost for using Google Cloud Platform is based on what features you use, and how much you use of each of them. To estimate your cost, you can use the [Google Cloud Platform price calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).

That link also includes a calculator for BigQuery pricing, which you'll need to use to estimate your cost.